# Setting controller variables not reliable from apex:commandButton

Tags: javascript, controller, actionfunction, commandbutton

I'm trying to set a variable inside my controller via an `actionFunction`, which is called by some Javascript, which is initially called by either by an `actionPanel` (with `styleClass='btn'`) or a `commandButton`.

If the caller is the `actionPanel` then the variable updates reliably. However with the `commandButton` I can see the updated value flash briefly before reverting to its previous value. Maybe one out of every six clicks of the button actually causes the new value to stick. Sometimes it can take a dozen or more tries, regardless of click frequency.

Can someone please explain what's going on here?

**PAGE**

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputPanel id="panel">
            <apex:outputText value="MyString = {!MyString}"/>
            <apex:actionFunction name="SetString" rerender="panel">
                <apex:param name="param1" value="" assignTo="{!MyString}"/>
            </apex:actionFunction>
            <script>
                function JSetString() {
                    SetString('{!MyString}' + '.');
                }
            </script>
            <apex:outputPanel onclick="JSetString()" styleClass="btn">
                Grow {!MyString} (works)
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:commandButton onclick="JSetString()" value="Grow {!MyString} (unreliable)" rerender="panel"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
global class MyController {

    public MyController() { MyString = 'hello'; }

    public String MyString {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Anything in the browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: @MikeChale Nothing but a mocking caret.

Comment: You need to add `onclick="JSetString(); return false;"` to your call and remove `rerender="panel"` parameter.

Comment: @mast0r That did it! Thanks very much :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command buttons translate to form input submit buttons.  Hence they have a default behavior to submit the form when clicked, which is conflicting with your javascript call.  If you change the call to `onclick="JSetString(); return false;"` as @mast0r pointed out the return false prevents the onclick event from bubbling up to the form and should fix your issues.  Removing the rerender on the command button also can't hurt since you're action function already has that.