# Getting 'live' controller variable values within Javascript

Tags: javascript, controller, rerender

I'm calling an actionFunction from Javascript to set a controller variable.

Even though the variable is being updated within the controller, when I subsequently access it from the same piece of script it still holds the old value. Now I understand that the updated value will become available after rerendering, but I'd like to access the new value later in the same script. Is there any way I can refresh the controller variable during the lifetime of the script, or is it easier just to create a JS variable that holds the new value, and use that instead?

### UPDATE

I'm not sure why this has been marked as a duplicate. This post describes a different issue, and the fix offered for my other post does not help with what I describe here.

**PAGE**

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputPanel id="panel">
            <apex:outputText value="MyString = {!MyString}"/>
            <apex:actionFunction name="SetString" rerender="panel">
                <apex:param name="param1" value="" assignTo="{!MyString}"/>
            </apex:actionFunction>
            <script>
                function JSetString()
                {
                    console.log('before: ' + '{!MyString}'); // shows last value assigned
                    SetString('{!MyString}' + '.');
                    console.log('after: ' + '{!MyString}'); // doesn't show updated value
                }
             </script>
            <apex:outputPanel onclick="JSetString()" styleClass="btn">
                Grow {!MyString} (works)
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
global class MyController {

    public MyController() { MyString = 'hello'; }

    public String MyString {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Please do not post same questions. This one is a copy of your first question: [Setting controller variables not reliable from apex:commandButton](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21036/setting-controller-variables-not-reliable-from-apexcommandbutton) You can edit a question instead if you want to make some changes.